# text in material icons in mat-toolbar alignment

Tags: angular, css, angular-material, material-design

I am using angular material, mat-toolbar to create a toolbar. I need to mat-icon and the related text to align one another (in two rows and center aligned)

Code:

```
<mat-toolbar class="secondary-toolbar">
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>apps</mat-icon>
    Dashboard
  </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

This code shows the image as below:

[image]

However, I require it to be something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to the dashboard span identifier such as class or id .

```
<span id="Dashboard">Dashboard</span>
```

Than, Add display flex styling .

```
#Dashboard
{
 display: flex;
 }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1srexj) Example .

Comment: thanks a ton for helping me with this. If I have more than one toolbar buttons next to each other the alignment is skewed up, how does that work with flex?

Comment: Just to add here, rather than increasing toolbar height, you could move `<span id="Dashboard">Dashboard</span>` little above using `margin-top: -20px`

Comment: Can you please let me know how it works with multiple items in the toolbar

Comment: What do you mean ? can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) display.

css

```
.secondary-toolbar button{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: I tried it without any luck, the icon and the text and inline and not column mode. Thanks.

Comment: I added id to dashboard span : 
 <span id="Dashboard">Dashboard</span>
and added this to the css :
#Dashboard{
  display: flex;
}
working for me.

Comment: @AmitBaranes is this along with what AmitChigadani suggestion?

Comment: I added this code to the stackblitz example you shared .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.button-icon-text {
    width: unset;
}

<button mat-icon-button class="button-icon-text" aria-label="Example icon-button with menu icon and text">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    <span>Menu</span>
</button>
```